# pandas to mysql error: `ValueError: database flavors mysql is not supported`

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, insert, load

I need to load data that i have in a DataFrame into mysql.
I tried to use the df.to_sql , following [this documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), that suggest using: `.to_sql(name, con, flavor='mysql', if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None)`

And i get this error: `ValueError: database flavors mysql is not supported`

How can i bypass this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flavor 'mysql' is deprecated in pandas version 0.19. You have to use the engine from sqlalchemy to create the connection with the database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE")
df.to_sql(name, con=engine, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None)
```

When defining your engine, you need to specify your user, password, host and database.